# Can I use boto to transfer a file from s3 to a remote machine without creating a local copy

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

I have S3 and two internal servers (IS1 and IS2).  I have files on S3 that I need to have transferred to IS2 but the python script (using boto) has to be run from IS1.  I'm currently running the transfer as S3 (boto) > IS1 (scp) > IS2.

I want to eliminate the intermediate transfer and just do S3 (boto) > IS2 but the script execution has to run on IS1.  I'm using get_contents_to_filename() for the transfer but I cannot get any syntax to work that will let me set the path to anything other than somewhere on IS1.  Is there a way to do this with boto?

Answer (score 0):

you can read the file content on IS1 and pipe it to IS2.

1. read content

use `get_contents_as_string` function to retrieve the content

2. pipe it

there're many ways. e.g.

```
echo "$content" | ssh auth@example.com "cat > file.txt"
```

or setup netcat on IS1 as sender and IS2 as receiver

IS2: `nc -l 8989 > file.txt` (listen on 8989)

IS1: `echo "$content" | nc example.com 8989`